# Grabbing a specific part of screen and making it an image that updates itself in Python

Tags: python

had a quick question. I would like to do something similar to what Michael Reeves did in his video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75ZuaSR8nQ at 6:49, where he took a part of his screen and made it an image that updates itself every __ milliseconds, how would i go about doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None)
>   Take a snapshot of the screen. The pixels inside the bounding box are returned as an “RGB” image on Windows or “RGBA” on OS X. If the bounding box is omitted, the entire screen is copied.

Example for use Tesseract to do OCR
You need install [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/Downloads.md), then set the path for tesseract.exe

Also install pytesseract, may be by `pip install pytesseract`

Of course, install PIL by `pip install Pillow`

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract

box = (300, 100, 1400, 600)
im = ImageGrab.grab(box)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)

# update text to your GUI
```

If you want to update the image periodly. No img1.show(), it will block there. Should use your selected GUI to do the update periodly. GUI maybe tkinter, cv, matplotlib, PySimpleGUI, ..... or use threading, maybe from python or from GUI to update each time.

Comment: thanks for responding, but that wasnt my problem, i just dont know how you could make it so when the image is shown, the image updates, i have an example,
img1 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox =(512, 990, 557, 1010)).convert('L')
img1.show()

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it alot